# How to override equals method in Java

Tags: java, overriding, equals

I am trying to override equals method in Java. I have a class `People` which basically has 2 data fields `name` and `age`. Now I want to override `equals` method so that I can check between 2 People objects.

My code is as follows

```
public boolean equals(People other){
    boolean result;
    if((other == null) || (getClass() != other.getClass())){
        result = false;
    } // end if
    else{
        People otherPeople = (People)other;
        result = name.equals(other.name) &&  age.equals(other.age);
    } // end else

    return result;
} // end equals
```

But when I write `age.equals(other.age)` it gives me error as equals method can only compare String and age is Integer.

### Solution

I used `==` operator as suggested and my problem is solved.

Comment: Hey how about this.age == other.age? :)

Comment: What is the data type for age? int OR Integer? Also, what version of JDK you are using?

Comment: "as equals method can only compare String" - Who told you equals method can only compare String? equals method belong to the Object class and any class created will have equals implementation by default. You can call equals on ANY Java class

Comment: I found this very useful: [What issues should be considered when overriding equals and hashCode in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/what-issues-should-be-considered-when-overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java)

Answer (score 161, accepted):

```
//Written by K@stackoverflow
public class Main {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        ArrayList<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();
        people.add(new Person("Subash Adhikari", 28));
        people.add(new Person("K", 28));
        people.add(new Person("StackOverflow", 4));
        people.add(new Person("Subash Adhikari", 28));

        for (int i = 0; i < people.size() - 1; i++) {
            for (int y = i + 1; y <= people.size() - 1; y++) {
                boolean check = people.get(i).equals(people.get(y));

                System.out.println("-- " + people.get(i).getName() + " - VS - " + people.get(y).getName());
                System.out.println(check);
            }
        }
    }
}

//written by K@stackoverflow
public class Person {
    private String name;
    private int age;

    public Person(String name, int age){
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }

        if (obj.getClass() != this.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }

        final Person other = (Person) obj;
        if ((this.name == null) ? (other.name != null) : !this.name.equals(other.name)) {
            return false;
        }

        if (this.age != other.age) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 3;
        hash = 53 * hash + (this.name != null ? this.name.hashCode() : 0);
        hash = 53 * hash + this.age;
        return hash;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

> run:
>
> -- Subash Adhikari - VS - K false
>
> -- Subash Adhikari - VS - StackOverflow false
>
> -- Subash Adhikari - VS - Subash Adhikari true
>
> -- K - VS - StackOverflow false
>
> -- K - VS - Subash Adhikari false
>
> -- StackOverflow - VS - Subash Adhikari false
>
> -- BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: what is `hash = 53 * hash` why you are using that?

Comment: Using `getClass()` is going to cause problems if the class gets subclassed, and is compared with an object of the super-class.

Comment: @Tuxdude edited the answer to use the .isAssignableFrom() method, which will be correct in instances of subclassing.  Regardless of the runtime type if it can be casted to a  person then this will work.

Comment: may be bcoz **53** is **prime number**,  have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/27609/3425489,       he commented while choosing numbers in `hashCode()`

Comment: The winning answer on this question has an excellent explanation of why you override hashCode() https://stackoverflow.com/a/27609/1992108

Comment: Consider using if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) ... rather than using the `instanceof`operator or `isAssignableFrom`. This will require exact type match, rather than subtype match. - Symmetric requirement. Also to compare `String` or other Object types, you can use `Objects.equals(this.name,other.name)`.

Comment: The "return true" statement in equals can be replaced by the previous condition "return this.age != other.age"

Answer (score 28):

Introducing a new method signature that changes the parameter types is called **overloading**:

```java
public boolean equals(People other){
```

Here `People` is different than `Object`.

When a method signature remains the identical to that of its superclass, it is called **overriding** and the `@Override` annotation helps distinguish the two at compile-time:

```java
@Override
public boolean equals(Object other){
```

Without seeing the actual declaration of `age`, it is difficult to say why the error appears.

Answer (score 20):

#### Item 10: Obey the general contract when overriding equals

> [According to Effective Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0134685997), Overriding the `equals` method seems simple, but there are many ways to get it wrong, and consequences can be dire. The easiest way to avoid problems is not to override the `equals` method, in which case each instance of the class is equal only to itself. This is the right thing to do if any of the following conditions apply:

- *Each instance of the class is inherently unique*. This is true for classes such as Thread that represent active entities rather than values. The equals implementation provided by Object has exactly the right behavior for these classes.
- *There is no need for the class to provide a “logical equality” test.* For example, java.util.regex.Pattern could have overridden equals to check whether two Pattern instances represented exactly the same regular expression, but the designers didn’t think that clients would need or want this functionality. Under these circumstances, the equals implementation inherited from Object is ideal.
- *A superclass has already overridden equals,* and the superclass behavior is appropriate for this class. For example, most Set implementations inherit their equals implementation from AbstractSet, List implementations from AbstractList, and Map implementations from AbstractMap.
- *The class is private or package-private*, and you are certain that its equals method will never be invoked. If you are extremely risk-averse, you can override the equals method to ensure that it isn’t invoked accidentally:

#### The `equals` method implements an equivalence relation. It has these properties:

- Reflexive: For any non-null reference value `x`, `x.equals(x)` must return true.
- Symmetric: For any non-null reference values `x` and `y`, `x.equals(y)` must return true if and only if y.equals(x) returns true.
- Transitive: For any non-null reference values `x`, `y`, `z`, if `x.equals(y)` returns `true` and `y.equals(z)` returns `true`, then `x.equals(z)` must return `true`.
- Consistent: For any non-null reference values `x` and `y`, multiple invocations of `x.equals(y)` must consistently return `true` or consistently return `false`, provided no information used in equals comparisons is modified.
- For any non-null reference value `x`, `x.equals(null)` must return `false`.

#### Here’s a recipe for a high-quality equals method:

1. Use the `==` operator to check if the argument is a reference to this object. If so, return true. This is just a performance optimization but one that is worth doing if the comparison is potentially expensive.
2. Use the `instanceof` operator to check if the argument has the correct type. If not, return false. Typically, the correct type is the class in which the method occurs. Occasionally, it is some interface implemented by this class. Use an interface if the class implements an interface that refines the equals contract to permit comparisons across classes that implement the interface. Collection interfaces such as Set, List, Map, and Map.Entry have this property.
3. Cast the argument to the correct type. Because this cast was preceded by an instanceof test, it is guaranteed to succeed.
4. For each “significant” field in the class, check if that field of the argument matches the corresponding field of this object. If all these tests succeed, return true; otherwise, return false. If the type in Step 2 is an interface, you must access the argument’s fields via interface methods; if the type is a class, you may be able to access the fields directly, depending on their accessibility.
5. For primitive fields whose type is not `float` or `double`, use the `==` operator for comparisons; for object reference fields, call the `equals` method recursively; for `float` fields, use the static `Float.compare(float, float)` method; and for `double` fields, use `Double.compare(double, double)`. The special treatment of float and double fields is made necessary by the existence of `Float.NaN`, `-0.0f` and the analogous double values; While you could compare `float` and `double` fields with the static methods `Float.equals` and `Double.equals`, this would entail autoboxing on every comparison, which would have poor performance. For `array` fields, apply these guidelines to each element. If every element in an array field is significant, use one of the `Arrays.equals` methods.
6. Some object reference fields may legitimately contain `null`. To avoid the possibility of a `NullPointerException`, check such fields for equality using the static method `Objects.equals(Object, Object)`.

   ```
   // Class with a typical equals method

   public final class PhoneNumber {

       private final short areaCode, prefix, lineNum;

       public PhoneNumber(int areaCode, int prefix, int lineNum) {

           this.areaCode = rangeCheck(areaCode,  999, "area code");

           this.prefix   = rangeCheck(prefix,    999, "prefix");

           this.lineNum  = rangeCheck(lineNum,  9999, "line num");

       }

       private static short rangeCheck(int val, int max, String arg) {

           if (val < 0 || val > max)

              throw new IllegalArgumentException(arg + ": " + val);

           return (short) val;

       }

       @Override public boolean equals(Object o) {
           if (o == this)
               return true;
           if (!(o instanceof PhoneNumber))
               return false;
           PhoneNumber pn = (PhoneNumber)o;
           return pn.lineNum == lineNum && pn.prefix == prefix
                   && pn.areaCode == areaCode;
       }
       ... // Remainder omitted

   }
   ```

Comment: Don't forget to mention that you have to override `hashCode()` as well. Also note, that since Java7 writing `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods has become much easier by using `Objects.equals()`, `Arrays.equals()` and `Objects.hashCode()`, `Arrays.hashCode()`.

Comment: Consider using `if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) ...` rather than using the instanceof operator. This will require *exact* type match, rather than subtype match. - Symmetric requirement.

Comment: @YoYo is correct... using instanceof could fail the symmetric property. If o is a subclass of PhoneNumber like maybe PhoneNumberWithExtension, and it overrides equals the same way by using instanceof, then o.equals(this) would fail the instanceof test while PhoneNumber.equals would pass it and return true (assuming all other PhoneNumber fields are equal).

Comment: Oracle is now encouraging the use of the `instanceof` pattern match introduced in Java 14, and finalized in Java 16: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75402885/501113

Answer (score 19):

I'm not sure of the details as you haven't posted the whole code, but:

- remember to override `hashCode()` as well
- the `equals` method should have `Object`, not `People` as its argument type. At the moment you are overloading, not overriding, the equals method, which probably isn't what you want, especially given that you check its type later.
- you can use `instanceof` to check it is a People object e.g. `if (!(other instanceof People)) { result = false;}`
- `equals` is used for all objects, but not primitives. I think you mean age is an `int` (primitive), in which case just use `==`. Note that an Integer (with a capital 'I') is an Object which should be compared with equals.

See [What issues should be considered when overriding equals and hashCode in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java) for more details.

Answer (score 13):

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object that){
  if(this == that) return true;//if both of them points the same address in memory

  if(!(that instanceof People)) return false; // if "that" is not a People or a childclass

  People thatPeople = (People)that; // than we can cast it to People safely

  return this.name.equals(thatPeople.name) && this.age == thatPeople.age;// if they have the same name and same age, then the 2 objects are equal unless they're pointing to different memory adresses
}
```

Comment: if `this.name` is null you get a `NullPointerException`

Answer (score 9):

When comparing objects in Java, you make a **semantic check**, comparing the **type and identifying state** of the objects to:

- itself (same instance)
- itself (clone, or reconstructed copy)
- other objects of different types
- other objects of the same type
- `null`

Rules:

- **Symmetry**: `a.equals(b) == b.equals(a)`
- `equals()` always yields `true` or `false`, but never a `NullpointerException`, `ClassCastException` or any other throwable

Comparison:

- **Type check**: both instances need to be of the **same** type, meaning you have to compare the actual classes for equality. This is often not correctly implemented, when developers use `instanceof` for type comparison (which only works as long as there are no subclasses, and violates the symmetry rule when `A extends B -> a instanceof b != b instanceof a)`.
- **Semantic check of identifying state**: Make sure you understand by which state the instances are identified. Persons may be identified by their social security number, but not by hair color (can be dyed), name (can be changed) or age (changes all the time). Only with value objects should you compare the full state (all non-transient fields), otherwise check only what identifies the instance.

For your `Person` class:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {

    // same instance
    if (obj == this) {
        return true;
    }
    // null
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    // type
    if (!getClass().equals(obj.getClass())) {
        return false;
    }
    // cast and compare state
    Person other = (Person) obj;
    return Objects.equals(name, other.name) && Objects.equals(age, other.age);
}
```

Reusable, generic utility class:

```
public final class Equals {

    private Equals() {
        // private constructor, no instances allowed
    }

    /**
     * Convenience equals implementation, does the object equality, null and type checking, and comparison of the identifying state
     *
     * @param instance       object instance (where the equals() is implemented)
     * @param other          other instance to compare to
     * @param stateAccessors stateAccessors for state to compare, optional
     * @param <T>            instance type
     * @return true when equals, false otherwise
     */
    public static <T> boolean as(T instance, Object other, Function<? super T, Object>... stateAccessors) {
        if (instance == null) {
            return other == null;
        }
        if (instance == other) {
            return true;
        }
        if (other == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!instance.getClass().equals(other.getClass())) {
            return false;
        }
        if (stateAccessors == null) {
            return true;
        }
        return Stream.of(stateAccessors).allMatch(s -> Objects.equals(s.apply(instance), s.apply((T) other)));
    }
}
```

For your `Person` class, using this utility class:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return Equals.as(this, obj, t -> t.name, t -> t.age);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Since I'm guessing `age` is of type `int`:

```
public boolean equals(Object other){
    boolean result;
    if((other == null) || (getClass() != other.getClass())){
        result = false;
    } // end if
    else{
        People otherPeople = (People)other;
        result = name.equals(otherPeople.name) &&  age == otherPeople.age;
    } // end else

    return result;
} // end equals
```

Comment: This will result in a `NullPointerException` if `name` is `null`.

Comment: @orien Not a big deal, maybe it is in the contract that `name` never gets assigned a `null` value...

Comment: @fortran So... maybe it's not a big deal ;)

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

```java
record Person ( String name , int age ) {}  
if( 
    new Person( "Carol" , 27 )              // Compiler auto-generates implicitly the constructor.
    .equals(                                // Compiler auto-generates implicitly the `equals` method.
        new Person( "Carol" , 42 ) 
    ) 
)                                           // Returns `false`, as the name matches but the age differs.
{ … }
```

## Details

While your specific problem is solved (using `==` for equality test between `int` primitive values), there is an alternative that eliminates the need to write that code.

## `record`

[Java 16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_16) brings the [record](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395) feature.

A record is a brief way to write a class whose main purpose is to transparently communicate immutable data. The compiler implicitly creates the constructor, getters, `equals` & `hashCode`, and `toString`.

### `equals` method provided automatically

The default implicit `equals` method compares each and every member field that you declared for the record. The members can be objects or primitives, both types are automatically compared in the default `equals` method.

For example, if you have a `Person` record carrying two fields, `name` & `age`, both of those fields are automatically compared to determine equality between a pair of `Person` objects.

```java
public record Person ( String name , int age ) {}
```

Try it.

```java
Person alice = new Person( "Alice" , 23 ) ;
Person alice2 = new Person( "Alice" , 23 ) ;
Person bob = new Person( "Bob" , 19 ) ;

boolean samePerson1 = alice.equals( alice2 ) ;  // true.
boolean samePerson2 = alice.equals( bob ) ;  // false.
```

You *can* override the `equals` method on a record, if you want a behavior other than the default. But if you do override `equals`, be sure to override `hashCode` for consistent logic, as [you would for a conventional Java class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27581/642706). And, think twice: Whenever adding methods to a `record`, reconsider if a record structure is really appropriate to that problem domain.

Tip: A `record` can be defined within another class, and even locally within a method.

Comment: this seems to be similar to the data classes in kotlin. :)

Answer (score 2):

if age is int you should use == if it is Integer object then you can use equals().
You also need to implement hashcode method if you override equals. Details of the contract is available in the javadoc of Object and also at various pages in web.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that I recently used:

```
public class Test {
    public String a;
    public long b;
    public Date c;
    public String d;
    
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(obj instanceof Test)) {
            return false;
        }
        Test testOther = (Test) obj;
        return (a != null ? a.equals(testOther.a) : testOther.a == null)
                && (b == testOther.b)
                && (c != null ? c.equals(testOther.c) : testOther.c == null)
                && (d != null ? d.equals(testOther.d) : testOther.d == null);
    }

}
```

Comment: I've tightened up this pattern (which is generated by both Eclipse and IntelliJ) so it is simpler and reads much easier: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75402885/501113

Answer (score 0):

For lazy programmers: `lombok` library is very easy and time saving. please have a look at [this link](https://projectlombok.org/)
instead of writing lines of codes and rules, you just need to apply this library in your IDE and then just @Data and it is Done.

```
import lombok.Data;

 @Data  // this is the magic word :D
public class pojo {

int price;
String currency;
String productName; 

}
```

in fact in the above code, @Data is a shortcut for

```
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
//or instead of all above @Data 

public class pojo {

int price;
String currency;
String productName;

}
```