# How do you detect if all the variables in two objects of the same type are the same?

Tags: java, variables, equality

Let's say I have two objects, `A` and `B` where..

```
Object A=new Object();
Object B=A;
```

These objects by default each have two ints: `int X` and `int Y`. First, in both `A` and `B`,

```
(X == 0) && (Y == 0)
```

So, you would say those two are equal, as would Java. Now, let's say we change `A.X` so that `A.X=2`. Now, `A` and `B` are no longer equal since

`A.X==2`

..but..

`B.X==0`

Java, however, still says they are equal.

```
(A.equals(B)) == true
(B.equals(A)) == true
```

So, how do you get around that?

Comment: Your variables are pointing at the same object. I'd be worried if they weren't equal!

Comment: A and B are the same object so B.X==2 also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By doing this `Object B=A;`, you are not creating a new object, but `B` is pointing to `A` only. So its only one object.

**So when you change `A.X = 2`, `B.X` is also 2 at its referring the same variable and hence equal.**

You may verify this by printing `B.X` value.

Comment: Ahh, okay. So is there anyway I can create an exact replica of the object as a new object without having to make a new constructor for it?

Comment: @StevenFontaine Create a **copy constructor**(to copy values from argument to self) in your class then use the same by passing `A` as arument to create object B as: `Object B = new Object(A);`. If you need help, please let me know.

Comment: Just one question.. What would go in the body of the constructor? Just several lines copying every variable from `A` to `B`?

Answer (score 1):

I think everyone (except Mr Singh) is missing a point here:

```
Object A=new Object(); // Implication is that this is really a user-defined class
Object B=A;
```

You only have one object here.  If you make a change to object A the same change will appear in object B, since they are the *exact same object*.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the .equals method of your class that contains the variables.  Take a look at this question: [How to override equals method in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8180430/how-to-override-equals-method-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

If `Object` is really your own class and not `java.lang.Object` (if it were then it would have those variables `x` and `y`) then it's really a bad class name choice.

Your class must override the `.equals` method as:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if(this == obj) return true;
    if(!(obj instanceof MyObject)) return false;
    MyObject other = (MyObject) obj;
    return other.x == this.x && other.y == this.y;
}
```