# Which function should I override when using indexOf() function

Tags: java

Which function should I override when using the indexOf() function in java. I have a array list, then I take in an input as the ID and create a object which contains the ID and all the other elements are null, then I need to pass that object and get the index of the element which contains that object

Comment: Why do you think you need to override a function at all?

Comment: because I need to get the index by passing an object which only contains a single element, which is the ID while all the other elements of the object is null

Comment: yes I need to search an object from the arraylist

Comment: There is something I don't understand: can you have several elements of your array with the same id? If yes, can't you use a `Map` instead with your identifiers as keys?

Answer (score 5):

The [equals() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8180430/how-to-override-equals-method-in-java)

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
  if (o instanceof MyObject) {
    //id comparison
    MyObject mo = (MyObject)o;
    return mo.id.equals(id);
  }
  return false;
}
```

Change `MyObject` to your class.

Remember to change `hashCode()` as well as @Hovercraft points out. equals and hashCode go together (read the javadoc for them). Else you might run into some nasty and possibly hard to find bugs.

An example:

With java 7+ you can do this:

```
public int hashCode() {
    return java.util.Objects.hashCode(id);
}
```

Comment: Then what should be the interface which I should call

Comment: You should probably mention that `Objects.hashCode()` is Java 7+ ;) Yeah, this is 2012, but...