# Checking a ArrayList of a class for duplicates

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList` of a class that holds information, and I want to add to objects to this list.  I want to check to see if that list already contains a number before adding it to a list.

Normally if it were just a list of strings I would just do something like this

```
if(!list.contains("this string")){
    list.add("this string");
}
```

but since this is a class, it has more than one variable per index.

An example of the class world be this:

```
private class From{
    private long threadID;
    private long date;
    private String address;
    private String body;
    private int type;
    private long id;

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj){
        if(obj != null){
            if(getClass() != obj.getClass()){
                return false;
            }else{
                final From from = (From)obj;
                if((this.address != null) ? (from.address != null) : !this.address.equals(from.address)){
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }else{
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

I want to see if there is already an entry with the same number, so am I going to have to manually loop through each index and check, or is there an easier way of doing what I want to do?

EDIT:

how i call it

```
HashSet<From> addresses = new HashSet<From>();
From f = new From();
                f.setAddress(messages.getString(3));
                f.setBody(messages.getString(0));
                f.setDate(messages.getLong(2));
                f.setThreadId(messages.getLong(1));
                f.setType(1);
                if(!addresses.contains(f.address)){
                    addresses.add(f);
                }
```

Comment: Consider using a `Map`

Answer (score 4):

Use a Set instead of a List. Sets dont allow duplicates

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html

You will also need to override equals in your class so the Set knows if two objects are equal

Example of overriding equals can be found here: [How to override equals method in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8180430/how-to-override-equals-method-in-java)

Comment: I override equals in my `Info` class but it never gets called when I put a breakpoint in the code. I edited my question to include more code with my call and my override

Comment: ... also override hashCode() when using a HashSet

Answer (score 1):

You have to override `equals(Object o)` for this. This is the place where you need to define the logic that would define the equality between two objects.

It is good practice to override `hashCode()` as well. Read more in the Javadocs for `Object`.

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be to `override equals()` for **Info** object such that two Info objects are equal if they both have the same number. before adding the element into the list just do the equals() test .

Answer (score 0):

You can still use the `contains` method; A [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) uses the `equals` method to determine if the item exists in the list.  But you must override `equals` in your `Info` object.