# java.util.List doesn't find elements

Tags: java, list, object, search

I need to consult you again since I'm stuck with the following problem:

To provide logging abilities to all my project, I use a selfmade library for logging, which includes static methods for access from all classes and objects, and also an ability to dump the log contents to a file on exit. This worked well for years now, now I need to extend the library to provide a function to use several "log channels", which each represent individual logs. Each log channel is an instance of the class "Log" (see below), and then added to a list (as in class ListTest3, see below). But when trying to get a specific log from the list by creating a dummy object which has the same channel name, always `-1` is returned, indicating that no object could be found. Why?

class Log:

```
public class Log {
  //...

  public String getChannel(){
    return channel;
  }

  //...

  public boolean equals(Log compare){
    // return getChannel().equals(compare.getChannel());
    return true;

    /**
     * used to contain a method to compare the channel names of the log
     * object itself and the provided object for comparison, now always
     * returns true for debugging purposes
     */
  }

  //...
}
```

For debugging, I created the following class ListTest3:

```
package test;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.LinkedList;

import logging.Log;

public class ListTest3 {
  public static void main(String[] args){
    List list = new LinkedList();
    Log logDefault = new Log();
    logDefault.setChannel("default");
    Log logAdvanced = new Log();
    logAdvanced.setChannel("advanced");
    Log logDebug = new Log();
    logDebug.setChannel("debug");

    list.add(logDefault);
    list.add(logAdvanced);
    list.add(logDebug);

    System.out.println("Index of logDefault: " + list.indexOf(logDefault));
    System.out.println("Index of logAdvanced: " + list.indexOf(logAdvanced));
    System.out.println("Index of logDebug: " + list.indexOf(logDebug));

    Log logDefaultDummy = new Log();
    logDefaultDummy.setChannel("default");
    System.out.println("Index of logDefaultDummy: " + list.indexOf(logDefaultDummy));

    Log logAdvancedDummy = new Log();
    logAdvancedDummy.setChannel("advanced");
    System.out.println("Index of logAdvancedDummy: " + list.indexOf(logAdvancedDummy));

    Log logDebugDummy = new Log();
    logDebugDummy.setChannel("debug");
    System.out.println("Index of logDebugDummy: " + list.indexOf(logDebugDummy));
  }
}
```

But instead of returning the indices of the three log objects when searching the list by their dummies, always `-1` is returned, as the following output shows:

```
Index of logDefault: 0
Index of logAdvanced: 1
Index of logDebug: 2
Index of logDefaultDummy: -1
Index of logAdvancedDummy: -1
Index of logDebugDummy: -1
```

Any help is very appreciated, since I don't know how to fix this problem. Thanks for reading that batch of text! ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to override equals method in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8180430/how-to-override-equals-method-in-java)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't properly overridden `equals()` and `hashCode()` in Object. Note that the correct signature of the method is

```
public boolean equals(Object o)
```

and not

```
public boolean equals(Log o)
```

When your intention is to override/implement a method, you should always use the `@Override` annotation on the method. This allows avoiding mistakes like the one you did.

Also, you're reinventing the wheel. Why don't you use a real, battle-tested, efficient logging framework such as logback or log4j?

Comment: Oh thanks, I completely missed that equals() requires an Object, not any class or a class of the same type. Don't know how this could occur to me :D Thank you very much for the quick reply!

Answer (score 1):

You equals method in the `Log` class has the wrong signature. It should be

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object compare){
    if (!(compare instanceof Log))
        return false;
    Log olog = (Log) compare;
    return getChannel().equals(olog.getChannel());
}
```

in order to override `Object`'s `equals` method and be used by `List`'s `indexOf` method.

Without overriding `equals`, you get the default implementation that checks reference equality, so your dummy instances are not equal to any instance in the List.

Comment: Thank you really much for the quick reply! I really appreciate that answers come so fast here at stackoverflow :D