# Java: 2 lists containing same elements in different order - How to delete same element?

Tags: java, list, arraylist

I have this situation:

```
List<MyClass> list_1 = new ArrayList<>();
List<MyClass> list_2 = new ArrayList<>();
list_1.add(elements...);
list_2.add(same elements...);
mixList(list_1);  //mixing the inner order between the elements
mixList(list_2);
MyClass mClass = list_1.get(5);  //for example place 5 
//TODO: How to remove above element who is exist
//in list_2 also, from list_2?
```

Note - also it is same elements, but it's not same objects:

```
//same elements, different objects
MyClass m1 = new MyClass("name", 1);
MyClass m2 = new MyClass("name", 1);
```

Comment: Does your class override `equals` and `hashCode`?

Comment: It can, why? for now not

Comment: Well if it does, it makes things much, much easier... you can just call `list_2.remove(list_1.get(5))` first...

Comment: Thanks, how to implement equals? in the 'intuitive' way?

Comment: @michael Added a link in my answer to ovveride equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem 1 :**

```
//same elements, different objects
MyClass m1 = new MyClass("name", 1);
MyClass m2 = new MyClass("name", 1);
```

To recognise them, you should implement `equals()` method.

To start with : [How to override equals method in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8180430/how-to-override-equals-method-in-java)

**Problem 2 :**

You can remove same items by writing

```
list2.removeAll(list1);
```

note that, you have to implements your `equals()` method to make it work.

Comment: Your `for` loop is entirely equivalent to `list2.removeAll(list1)`.