# Overriding the hashCode( ) in java for a class that contains an array

Tags: java, class, hashmap, overriding

I have a class in java which contains two integers and an array of integers as members and I want to make a hash map with the above object as key. How should i override the equals operator and hashCode() such that the object which have same Integer values as that of members and same entries in the array get the same Hash Code?(or is such a thing even possible) Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Override equals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8180430/how-to-override-equals-method-in-java)

Comment: I wrote this a while back as a way of doing what your are trying to do in a consistant way. Might be useful: http://sourceforge.net/p/tus/code/HEAD/tree/tjacobs/util/PrimaryKey.java

Comment: @sam2090 I think this question is asking for how to correct use `equals` and `hashCode` on *arrays*, not on integers.

Comment: @ControlAltDel Was that "while back" before 1.5?

Comment: @laune I think we were at 1.5 at the time. To be honest, I recall that even when I was coding this up, I didn't think it was such an elegant solution. But I thought I'd mention it.

Comment: @sam2090 yes that's what i am looking for.I want to know how to correct equals for the array member of class and then how to implement the corresponding hash function.

Comment: Your question have multiple answers. Mark as answer the one that you feel helped you the best as a way to appreciate the author and also, for future readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To calculate a hashcode for the int array you can use `java.util.Arrays.hashcode(int[])`.

If you look at its implementation:

```
public static int hashCode(int a[]) {
    if (a == null)
        return 0;

    int result = 1;
    for (int element : a)
        result = 31 * result + element;

    return result;
}
```

you can derive an idea how to calculate a hash code for your class which should be based on the values of your two integers and the integer array:

```
public class MyClass {
    private int a, b;
    private int[] array;

    public int hashCode() {
         return (31 * (31 * Arrays.hashCode(array) + a)) + b;
    }
```

To equals implementation can look like:

```
    public int equals(Object o) {
         if (o instanceof of MyClass) {
             MyClass m = (MyClass)o;
             return m.a == a && m.b == b && Arrays.equals(m.array, array);
         }
         else 
             return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `java.util.Arrays#equals(int[], int[])` and `Arrays.hashCode(int[])`

Comment: Just a cautioning remark that Arrays.equals and Arrays.hashCode cannot be applied to *arbitrary* arrays: check Arrays.deepEquals and Arrays.deepHashCode.

Comment: @laune certainly it's better now.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for array equality using the `java.util.`**`Arrays`** class:

```
int[] array1 = { 1, 2, 3 };
int[] array2 = { 1, 2, 3 };

boolean equal = Arrays.equals(array1, array2) // --> true
```

To calculate the hash code of an array, the same class can help you out as well:

```
int hash = Arrays.hashCode(new int[] { 1, 2, 3 })
```

Note that the class has overloaded methods for all array types - including `Object[]`.