# Check if a contains an object in Java

Tags: java, queue

I've the following Object,

```
public class Pair {
    private int row;
    private int col;

    public Pair(int row, int col){
        this.row = row;
        this.col = col;
    }

    public int getRow(){
        return row;
    }
    public int getCol(){
        return col;
    }
}
```

I'm storing these pairs in a queue, but wan't to check if the Queue contains the Pair already. This is my code.

```
Queue<Pair> queue = new LinkedList<>();
if(!queue.contains(new Pair(curr.getRow(), curr.getCol()){
 //do something
}
```

This is not working and the Queue is storing duplicate values. Can someone help mw understand why and what's the way to fix it?

Comment: Override equals() to implement a custom comparison. Right now it only check object equality.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You aren't overriding [`Object.equals(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) so you get equality only for reference identity. You need to add something like

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o instanceof Pair) {
        Pair other = (Pair) o;
        return row == other.row && col == other.col;
    }
    return false;
}
```

and whenever you override `equals` it's strongly recommended that you override [`Object.hashCode()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode--) as well (to work with `HashSet`s for example) like

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Integer.hashCode(row) + Integer.hashCode(col);
}
```

Finally, you might as well override [`Object.toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--) so you can display these `Pair`s easily. Something like,

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return String.format("Pair: (%d, %d)", row, col);
}
```

Comment: Maybe add a explaination/link to the `equals` and `hashcode` contract?

Answer (score 0):

You should override the equals method in you Pair class. Check out this reference [How to override equals method in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8180430/how-to-override-equals-method-in-java)