# override equals of a custom object (called by contains method of a list)

Tags: java, compare

I have two types of user, LibraUsers and GenesysUser. Each have their own properties, but some are similar.

I need to find the differences between two lists of these types of users. Made a small program to illustrate my problem - My issue is that I have duplicate entries in my difference list, the compare method on the list does not seem to do its job. I've read that I should override the equals method, and also the hashcode (in this case of the LibraUser). I tried that using an apache function, but it did not work. 
The question therefore is, what are the alternatives for solving this problem?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

// one class needs to have a main() method
public class HelloWorld {
    public static List<LibraUser> libraUsers = new ArrayList<LibraUser>();
    public static List<GenesysUser> genesysUsers = new ArrayList<GenesysUser>();
    public static List<LibraUser> difference = new ArrayList<LibraUser>();

    public static void initialiseGenesysUsers() {
        // GenesysUser(String alias, String firstname, String lastname, String email)
        genesysUsers.add(new GenesysUser("Donna", "Donna", "Paulsen", "donna@gmail.com", true));
        genesysUsers.add(new GenesysUser("TheHarv", "Harvey", "Specter", "harvey@gmail.com", true));
        genesysUsers.add(new GenesysUser("Rache", "Rachel", "Zane", "rachel@gmail.com", true));
        genesysUsers.add(new GenesysUser("Mike", "Mike", "Ross", "mike@gmail.com", true));
    }

    public static void initialiseLibraUsers() {
        // LibraUser(String name, String email, String telephone) {
        libraUsers.add(new LibraUser("Louis", "louis@gmail.com", "0447521082"));
        libraUsers.add(new LibraUser("Jessica", "jessica@gmail.com", "0447521044"));
        libraUsers.add(new LibraUser("Mike", "mike@gmail.com", ""));
    }

    public static void getDifference() {
        for (LibraUser librauser : libraUsers) {
            for (GenesysUser genesysuser : genesysUsers) {
                String genusername = genesysuser.getFirstname();
                LibraUser dummy = new LibraUser(genusername, genesysuser.getEmail(), "");
                if (!difference.contains(dummy)) {
                    // do the actual comparison using the relevant keys and insert into a new list
                    if (!librauser.getUsername().equals(genusername)) {
                        difference.add(dummy);
                    }
                }
            } // inner for loop
        }// outer for loop
    }

    public static void printDifference() {
        for (LibraUser usr : difference) {
            System.out.println(usr.getUsername());
        }
    }

    // arguments are passed using the text field below this editor
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        initialiseGenesysUsers();
        initialiseLibraUsers();

        getDifference();
        printDifference();
    }
}

public class GenesysUser {
    private String Alias;
    private String Firstname;
    private String Lastname;
    private String Email;
    private boolean Active;

    public GenesysUser(String alias, String firstname, String lastname, String email, boolean active) {
        Alias = alias;
        Firstname = firstname;
        Lastname = lastname;
        Email = email;
        Active = active;
    }

    public String getAlias() {
        return Alias;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return Firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return Lastname;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return Email;
    }

    public void setAlias(String alias) {
        Alias = alias;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        Firstname = firstname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        Lastname = lastname;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        Email = email;
    }

    public void setActive(boolean active) {
        Active = active;
    }

    public boolean getActive() {
        return Active;
    }
}

public class LibraUser {
    private String username;
    private String email;
    private String telephone;

    public LibraUser(String username, String email, String telephone) {
        this.username = username;
        this.email = email;
        this.telephone = telephone;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return this.username;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return this.email;
    }

    public String getTelephone() {
        return this.telephone;
    }

    public void setName(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public void setTelephone(String telephone) {
        this.telephone = telephone;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (o == this)
            return true;
        if (!(o instanceof LibraUser)) {
            return false;
        }

        LibraUser user = (LibraUser) o;

        return new EqualsBuilder()
            .append(username, user.getUsername())
            .append(email, user.getEmail())
            .isEquals();
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return new HashCodeBuilder(17, 37)
            .append(username)
            .append(email)
            .toHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java .... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8180430/how-to-override-equals-method-in-java

Comment: admittedly that was a mistake, the bigger question still stands...

Comment: I copy and pasted from my actual code to my dummy code to provide more information. User should be LibraUser.

Comment: I just tried your way - it works except when I add the same user to both lists (genesys and libra) then it does not pick up a duplicate.Example when I add this line: libraUsers.add(new LibraUser("Mike", "mike@gmail.com", ""));

Comment: Ok, now we're talking. Notice that I took the liberty to add this line to your code, since it is quite important. Your issue is the `getDifference` method the both `for` loops. You first take the first entry from `libraUsers` and compare it with every entry in `genesysUsers`. No what happens? Is Donna that first entry (in libraUsers I mean)? No -> add to difference. Is Harvey that first entry? No -> add. Or Rachel or Mike? No for both. You check the entry "Mike" from "libraUsers" as the third iteration of the outer loop, but you've added "Mike" from "genesysUsers" already to differences.

Comment: So I've pointed you to the issue in that algo, now take same time and try to find a better solution, you'll learn a lot from that experience. As a hint: try to use only one `for` (and only that loop, not an additional "while" loop).

Comment: hey Tom, long story short - I made a mockup to ask the question here, and I got the mockup working. However when I do the same in my working project code, it does not work. I then decided to take out the place where I call "contains" on the list, and write my own code that basically iterates through both lists. This code then works as I expect. There may be some weird relationship between classes causing the equals method not to the called in my working project case. Thanks for your effort though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use .equals instead of == to test the equality

```
if(librauser.getUsername() != genusername)
```

should be replaced with

```
if(!librauser.getUsername().equqls(genusername))
```

Comment: hi @murthy, thanks for your answer - i have replaced the '==' with equals, and put a not sign at the next condition. I still get duplicates in my differences list though...

Comment: Can you post that code here of the condition you have made

Comment: sure - please check the original question, i've added the two override methods.