# Modified LinkedList (2 integers per node) with ListIterator

Tags: java, linked-list, listiterator

I'm writing a code to save, delete and load a person's height and weight data. I have created 2 classes:

```
class Person {
    private int height;
    private int weight;

    public Person(int h, int w) {
        height = h;
        weight = w;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public int getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    public String getValues() {
        return ("Height "+height+" and weight "+weight);
    }
}


class DataModified {        //Problem in this class
    private LinkedList<Person> lList;
    private ListIterator<Person> lIter;

    public DataModified() {
        lList = new LinkedList<Person>();
        lIter = lList.listIterator();
    }

    public void save(Person p) {        
        Person p1, p2;                                  //p1: Data needed to be saved
        p1 = new Person(p.getHeight(), p.getWeight());  //p2: Data already on the list
        boolean alreadyExist = false;
        lIter = lList.listIterator();
        while(lIter.hasNext()) {        
            p2 = lIter.next();      
            if ((p2.getHeight() == p1.getHeight()) && (p2.getWeight() == p1.getWeight())) {
                alreadyExist = true;        
            }
        }
        if(alreadyExist) {
            System.out.println("Person: " + p1.getValues() + " had already been on the list.");
        }
        else {
            lIter.add(p1);
            System.out.println("Person: " + p1.getValues() + " is added to the list.");
        }
    }

    public void delete(Person p) {
        Person p3, p2;                                  //p3: Data needed to be deleted
        p3 = new Person(p.getHeight(), p.getWeight());  
        boolean alreadyExist = false;
        lIter = lList.listIterator();
        while(lIter.hasNext()) {        
            p2 = lIter.next();      
            if ((p2.getHeight() == p3.getHeight()) && (p2.getWeight() == p3.getWeight())) {
                alreadyExist = true;        
            }
        }
        if(alreadyExist) {
            lIter.remove();
            System.out.println("Person: " + p3.getValues() + " is deleted from the list.");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Person: " + p3.getValues() + " is not on the list.");
        }
    }

    public void load() {            //Problem
        lIter = lList.listIterator();
        Person p2;
        for(int i = 1; lIter.hasNext(); i++){
            p2 = lIter.next();
            System.out.println("Person "+i+" has "+p2.getValues());
        }
    }
}
```

I had tested these 3 methods from class `DataModified`: I first save data from 3 persons, then delete 1 person and load the rest. However, the last method prints not the 2 persons on the list, but the person I have deleted before.

My question are:

1. What is wrong with my code? Why did the `load()` method work like that?
2. I noticed that after iterating, I can only modified the `lIter`. So are `lList` and `lIter` the same list or 2 separated lists? If they are not the same, how can I give `lList` the data from `lIter`?
3. Is there a way to stop the iteration of a list?

Comment: You should use [`.equals()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8180430/how-to-override-equals-method-in-java) to set `alreadyExist`

Comment: In `delete()`, once you find your `Person` you set `alreadyExist` to `true` the first time you find someone and keep going.  So once it's set, it's set for EVERYONE.  If you find your Person in the list in position 1, you'll delete him, but then you'll delete the next person and so on.  All of your while loops need to say `while (lIter.hasNext() && !alreadyExists)`

Comment: There are too many issues with the way you have designed your methods. As @River mentioned, override equals and hashcode for your Person class and use it to check for already existing case in LinkedList. In delete method you are using remove() without any parameter. It will just remove the head of linked list and not the Person p you are trying to delete. You would be able to use remove(Object o) method instead if you override equals.

Comment: *Unrelated:* Why do you have `ListIterator` as a *field*? Get rid of it, and declare as local variable where needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others are pointing out, you definitely have a bug in your `delete` method.  As written, if the target Person is found in the list, then the last Person in the list will be removed, not the target.  You really need to be able to cut out of the while loop when you find the person and remove it immediately instead of continuing the loop.

To answer your questions:

1. What's wrong? The bug in delete that removes the wrong Person.
2. Are `lList` and `lIter` the same list?  Conceptually yes, technically no.  `lList` is the list itself, and `lIter` is the Iterator acting on that list.  It's not a list itself.  It's an Iterator.  But the data it's working on is definitely the same list.
3. How to stop iteration? You have a few options. The easiest for how your code is currently written is a `break` statement. It stops execution of the current loop and resumes executing outside the block.  In both your add and delete methods, it would make sense to break right after `alreadyExist` is set to true.  Another option, suggested first by jiveturkey, is to add `alreadyExist` as a condition to the while loops.  Then you'll only continue iterating if both there are more items to iterate over and `alreadyExist` hasn't yet been set to true. A third option would be to do the real work (i.e delete) as soon as you find the Person and then return from the method entirely.

Beyond that, some unsolicited general advice :)

- You're comparing Person objects in multiple methods.  Over time, this will get hard to maintain, so it would be better to define the comparison in one place.  Java comes with an `equals` method for this.  It's in every `Object`, but the default implementation won't help you, so you want to override it.  In your case, you consider two distinct Person objects to be conceptually equal if their heights and weights are equal.  So override the equals() method in Person to return true iff the height and weight are equal.  See [How to override equals method in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8180430/how-to-override-equals-method-in-java) or http://users.csc.calpoly.edu/~gfisher/classes/102/info/howToOverrideEquals.html for some tips.  If you override `equals`, you also need to override `hashCode`.
- You're making copies of the Person parameters.  The exact object being passed in is not the actual object being added or deleted from the list; the copy is.  You could just use the paremeter.  In the best case, you currently have an unnecessary performance hit (creating extra objects).  In the worst case you'll hit bugs.
- `lIter` is set both in the constructor and in every method. If you don't need to store its current state across method calls, then it should probably be just a local variable, used for a method and then discarded.
- `getValues()` is currently just being used to make the object human-readable.  That's a common problem, and the task given to `toString()`, also defined in `Object` and overridable in any class you write.  All you'd need to do to take advantage of it is rename `getValues` to `toString`. Then you could just use it in a log message directly. Example below.

Here's how I would then rewrite delete, assuming a good `equals` method in `Person`, and `getValues` renamed to `toString`:

```
public void delete(Person p) {
    boolean alreadyExist = false;
    ListIterator definitelyNotLIter = lList.listIterator();
    while(definitelyNotLIter.hasNext()) {        
        Person current = definitelyNotLIter.next();      
        if (p.equals(current)) {
            alreadyExist = true;
            definitelyNotLIter.remove();

            // Option 1:
            break;  // next line to execute will be the if(alreadyExist) block

            // Option 2:
            // put your successful delete logging here
            // return;
            // and leave the failed delete logging outside the loop

            // Option 3:
            // Do nothing. The looping will continue, and you'd have a deleteAll method, where multiple items would get deleted if you managed to get duplicates in the list.
            // You actually wouldn't need alreadyExist any more.

            // I'd go with option 1, myself
        }
    }
    if(alreadyExist) {
        System.out.println("Person: " + p + " is deleted from the list."); // p.toString() will get called
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Person: " + p + " is not on the list."); // p.toString() will get called
    }
}
```

Comment: So silly that your (very comprehensive) answer is currently tied with a blatantly incorrect answer, even with my +1. Let's hope others feel the same. Using `toString` is also a very good suggestion.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I never expect to receive such detailed answer. I was under the impression that `remove()` and `add()` work similar to each other, and thus keep trying to find error in my `load()` method. `break` and `toString()` are definitely a life saver.

Comment: @River Yeah, I'm not trying to communicate I fully agree with the other answer (definitely not quite right, but it's on the right track), but just that I couldn't claim credit to that approach.  Using the boolean as another condition didn't jump out at me, but may be considered cleaner than `break` statements, so I felt it should be included. And thanks for the +1!

Answer (score 1):

In `delete()`, once you find your Person you set `alreadyExist` to `true` the first time you find someone and keep going. So once it's set, it's set for EVERYONE. If you find your Person in the list in position 1, you'll delete him, but then you'll delete the next person and so on. All of your while loops need to say.

```
while (!alreadyExists && lIter.hasNext()) {        
    p2 = lIter.next();      
    if ((p2.getHeight() == p1.getHeight()) && (p2.getWeight() == p1.getWeight())) {
            alreadyExist = true;
            lIter.remove();
        }
    }

    // Delete the if/else code
```

You should probably get rid of the member variable:

```
private ListIterator<Person> lIter;
```

Comment: This answer is incorrect, only one item is deleted from the list.

Comment: Is the suggested solution incorrect or the diagnosis?

Comment: Diagnosis. Solution isn't ideal but works. A correct solution with a incorrect diagnosis isn't worth much.

Comment: Arggghhh.  Being able to see parenthesis is pretty important I guess.

Comment: I appreciate your help! Also thank @River for pointing that out, I got confused for a second.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `delete` method:

You loop through the entire list before removing anything. [`ListIterator.remove` only deletes the last item returned by `next()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html#remove()). You need to break when you find the item that already exists:

```
while(lIter.hasNext()) {        
    p2 = lIter.next();      
    if ((p2.getHeight() == p3.getHeight()) && (p2.getWeight() == p3.getWeight())) {
        alreadyExist = true;   
        break;     
    }
}
```

---

Additionally, the way you are comparing `Person` objects should really be done in a `equals()` method, as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8180430/how-to-override-equals-method-in-java).

---

Finally, your creation/use of an extra `Person` that is a duplicate of parameter `p` is entirely unnecessary here. Just use `p` instead of `p1` (in `save`) and `p3` (in `delete`).

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer and edit my question! It's a pity but ojchase gave me clear answers for both 3 questions, so I need to choose them over you.

Comment: Not a problem, his answer turned out better anyways.

Comment: +1 That downvote is definitely odd. This answer is definitely correct, with a good link and explanation.

Answer (score 0):

From [Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html):

> void remove() Removes from the list the ***LAST*** element that was returned
>   by next() or previous()

**But** when you reach the required `Person` Object, you continue iteration the **next** `Person` Object.

What you need is to **`break`** the `while` loop once it finds the target object.

```
if ((p2.getHeight()==p3.getHeight())&&(p2.getWeight()==p3.getWeight())){
      alreadyExist = true;
      break;        
}
```

Now the last element is the required Object, you can now use `remove()`.

```
if(alreadyExist) {lIter.remove();}
```

Comment: I didn't downvote your answer but just wanna confirm as documentation mentions  -> public E remove(): Retrieves and removes the head (first element) of this list.

Comment: @River No kidding! And who are you to judge that it adds nothing useful, and how did ya know that I even looked at your answer!?

Comment: @digidude You're talking about [The Remove in LinkedList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#remove()) and not the `ListIterator`.. Please open the link of documentation I provided in my answer.

Comment: @Yahya don't know if I deserved that.  Thx.

Comment: @River your comments are full of contradiction! My comment was based on your comment. But in your second comment you negate your first comment. You need to keep your hair on though!

Comment: @River my bad. I failed to realize that he was doing lIter.remove()

Comment: Thanks for helping me!