# How to compare two object properties?

Tags: java, oop, compare

```
public class CellAtt {
    private String brand;
    private long serial;
    private double price;

    public CellAtt(String brand, long serial, double price) {
        this.brand = brand;
        this.serial = serial;
        this.price = price;
    }
    public boolean Compare(Object c1,Object c2) {

    }

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        CellAtt c1 = new CellAtt("nokia",4536895,3600.00);
        CellAtt c2 = new CellAtt("Samsung",4536895,3600.00);
    }
}
```

I have created two objects in `main.java`.

I want to compare two object properties, `Brand` and `Price`. If brand and price are the same, it must return `true`, or else `false`. Hope I'm clear.

Comment: What is the meaning of comparing Brand and Price?

Comment: This is from my assignments, the question is in this way..                           
 "The design should allow for one cell phone to be compared to another cell phone for equality. Two cell phone objects are considered equal if they have the same brand and the same price."

Comment: So your assignment include to compare `"nokia"  == 3600.00`?

Comment: Ok ok I get it now. You are asking something like this  `obj1.price == obj2.price` and `obj1.brand.equals(obj2.brand)`. Since your attributes are `private`, you have implemented a method and you do not know how to implement that method. Is that the question?

Comment: No, They are two objects if the brand of object 1 is equal to brand of object 2 then true  and same procedure follows with the price

Comment: Exactly. How to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

In your `Compare` method:

```
public boolean Compare(Object c1,Object c2){
   c1 = (CellAtt)c1;
   c2 = (CellAtt)c2; 
}
```

method `return true` if `c1.brand.equals(c2.brand) && c1.price == c2.price` else `return false`.

Alternatively, you can override `equals()` method of `Object` class

Comment: Don't compare strings with "==".　`Object c1` has no field `brand` or `price`.

Comment: Yes got my mistake, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to tackle this problem would be to override the Object.equals() function which is built for this very specific purpose. More details cand be found here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/object_equals.htm

Answer (score 0):

Best and good way to do this is, override the [`equals()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) method in [`Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) class:

```
public boolean equals(Object c){
    if (c == null)
        return false;

    if (!CellAtt.class.isAssignableFrom(c.getClass()))
        return false;

    CellAtt obj = (CellAtt) c;
    
    return this.brand.equals(obj.brand) && this.price == obj.price;
}
```

read this to understand [how to override equals() in Object class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8180430/how-to-override-equals-method-in-java)

If you strictly want to implement a method by yourself do this:

Modify the `compare()` in `CellAtt` class.

```
public boolean compare(CellAtt c){
    if (c == null)
        return false;

    return this.brand.equals(c.brand) && this.price == c.price;
}
```

Then in the `Main` class, you can invoke the method like below:

```
boolean res = c1.compare(c2);
System.out.println(res);//this is added to check output
```

### UPDATE

**Comlete code:**

`CellAtt` class:

```
public class CellAtt {
    private String brand;
    private long serial;
    private double price;

    public CellAtt(String brand, long serial, double price) {
        this.brand = brand;
        this.serial = serial;
        this.price = price;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object c){
        if (c == null)
            return false;

        if (!CellAtt.class.isAssignableFrom(c.getClass()))
            return false;

        CellAtt obj = (CellAtt) c;

        return this.brand.equals(obj.brand) && this.price == obj.price;
    }
}
```

`Main` class:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CellAtt c1 = new CellAtt("nokia",4536895,3600.00);
        CellAtt c2 = new CellAtt("samsung",4536895,3600.00);
        
        boolean res = c1.equals(c2);
        System.out.println(res);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting this error " the method compare(CellAtt) is undefined for type CellAtt

Comment: check the argument data type, or may be spell mistake. copy and paste this and see, it is worked or not.

Comment: @SreemanJuvvadi glad to help. So you can accept this answer. It will help who find answers to the question like this.

Comment: `c1.equals("abc")` throws ClassCastException.

Answer (score -1):

```
public boolean Compare(Object c1,Object c2) {
    return c1.brand == c2.brand && c1.price == c2.price;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public  boolean Compare(Object c1, Object c2) {

        if(c1 == null || c2 == null)
            return false;

        CellAtt ca1=(CellAtt)c1;
        CellAtt ca2=(CellAtt)c2;

        if(ca1.brand.equals(ca2.brand) && ca1.price == ca2.price)
            return true;

    return false;
}
```

Comment: How to call Campare method in Main.java ?

Comment: new CellAtt().Compare(c1,c2);

Answer (score -1):

```
public class CellAtt {
    private String brand;
    private long serial;
    private double price;

    public CellAtt(String brand, long serial, double price) {
        this.brand = brand;
        this.serial = serial;
        this.price = price;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 42;
        hash = 29 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.brand);
        hash = 29 * hash + (int) (this.serial ^ (this.serial >>> 32));
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final CellAtt other = (CellAtt) obj;
        if (this.serial != other.serial) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.brand, other.brand)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```