# ArrayList contains method not work as I would expect?

Tags: java, arraylist

ArrayList use `equals()` in its `contains` method to see if provide object equals any item in the list as the document say:

> Returns true if this list contains the specified element. More
>   formally, returns true if and only if this list contains at least one
>   element e such that (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e)). see [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains-java.lang.Object-)

I have this class

```
class Foo
{
  private String value;
  public Foo(String value)
  {
    this.value = value;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o)
  {
    return o == null ? this.value == null : o.toString().equals(this.value);
  }
}
```

I want to use `contains` method to check if item exists like this

```
List<Foo> list = new ArrayList<Foo>();

Foo item1 = new Foo("item1");
Foo item2 = new Foo("item2");
list.add(item1);
list.add(item2);

System.out.println(item1.equals("item1"));       //return true
System.out.println(list.contains("item1"));      //false !! why?!
```

but `contains` method return `false` , while `item1.equals("item1")` return `true`.

why `contains` return false when it use `equals` method for provided object

Comment: `o` is the parameter passed into `contains` (in this case a `String`), `e` is the element of the `List` (your class `Foo`) - `o.equals(e)` is not the same as `e.equals(o)`

Comment: Find the actual object type in the list, not a string. I.E find a FOO in a list of FOOs and not a STRING in a list of FOOs

Comment: Why would you use "@override" on your equals() method? your class doesn't extend any other class, I think that your equal() is lik any other method you would declare.

Comment: @ZiMtyth No. He's overriding it from the `Object` class. It is strongly recommended that you add this annotation, to be sure you have the good signature

Comment: @nathan , thank you for the clarification :)

Comment: @Ali FYI, the `Lists` implementations use the `hashCode` method to do a pre-sorting. You should definitely take a look at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8180430/how-to-override-equals-method-in-java **EDIT** Actually I tagged it as a dupe, because that's the reference for incorrect equals implementations.

Comment: I suggest you to read, why should we always override `hashCode` when we are overriding `equals`. I dont think it will work even after passing `new Foo("item1")`. https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-override-the-hashCode-and-equals-method-in-Java-HashMap/answer/Vivek-Singh-619?srid=Crub

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your `equals()` implementation violates the symmetric principle :

> It is symmetric: for any non-null reference values x and y,
>   x.equals(y) should return true if and only if y.equals(x) returns
>   true.

`item1.equals("item1")` returns `true`

while

`"item1".equals(item1)` returns `false`.

So you should not expect that `Collection` method such as `contains()` works in a consistent way.

As a general rule, `equals()` overriding should not try to interoperate with other classes but only with instances of the underlying class.

In your case, it works only for `String` parameter passed to the method.
You should rather make it working for `Foo` instances parameter:

```
  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
     if (!(o instanceof Foo){ 
       return false;
     }
     Foo other = (Foo) o;
     return Objects.equals(other.value, this.value);
  }
```

Comment: thanks I did got it now

Comment: You are welcome. I edited with an alternative implementation.

Comment: This is the key answer. The root problem is the OP's implementation of `equal`. Don't feel bad though. It's a common error in Java

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is that your equality is not symmetric. `Foo == String` does not imply `String == Foo`.

If you look at the implementation of [`ArrayList.contains`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.contains%28java.lang.Object%29) you'll see that it calls `objectToFind.equals(objectInList)`, which may be contrary to what you were expecting:

```
o.equals(elementData[i])
```

So in your case that's `String.equals(Foo)`. Because `String.equals` will return false for anything that's not a String, `ArrayList.contains` returns false.

Comment: thanks this was helpful

Answer (score 5):

Looking at the docs [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) the contains will use the equals method on the string "item1" and not the equals method on item1. e.g.

```
"item1".equals(item1)
```

and not

```
item1.equals("item1")
```

You could use `list.contains(new Foo("item1"))` instead.

Comment: thanks for your help

Answer (score 4):

While `item1.equals("item1")` is true, `"item1".equals(item1)` will be false. Having a non-symmetric equals relation causes a lot of confusion.

In general, you want `equals` to only be true among classes you control (usually only the exact class you're comparing), so that you can ensure that the relation is symmetric. (And to avoid further confusion, always define `hashCode` whenever you define `equals`.)

Comment: thanks I did got it now

Answer (score 2):

YOUR Equals method is not considering the instance of the Object, so is wrongly implemented

you have a list of Foos and you want to know if the list contains a STRING

this:

```
System.out.println(list.contains("item1"));
```

is not the same as

```
System.out.println(list.contains(new Foo("item1")));
```

because

```
 new Foo("item1") never ever will return true on equals to the string "item1"
```

---

edit:

contains in the ArrayList is implemented as

```
    @Override
    public int indexOf(Object o) {
        E[] a = this.a;
        if (o == null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
                if (a[i] == null)
                    return i;
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
                if (o.equals(a[i]))
                    return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

so this part is the important one

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
         if (o.equals(a[i]))
                  return i;
```

as you can see

```
  o.equals(a[i])
```

means

```
  String.equals(Foo)
```

which is NOT the same as what you did:

```
  Foo.equals(String)
```

you are breaking a rule of **symmetry**, that is the reason why is not working!

Comment: i expect to return true since I override equals method in `Foo`

Comment: *new Foo("item1") never ever will return true on equals to the string "item1"* that's just not true. You can cook up an equals() implementation to do exactly that

Comment: @ΦX __`new Foo("item1")` never ever will return true on equals to the string "item1"__ Why not? If I override my `equals` method in `Foo` class and make it return true always? You probably meant the other way around: __the string "item1" never ever will return true on equals to new Foo("item1")__

Comment: thanks for your clarification

Answer (score 2):

Your equals implementation is clearly incorrect.

You should read [chapter 3](http://fpl.cs.depaul.edu/jriely/450/extras/Chapter3.pdf) of Joshua Bloch's "Effective Java" to learn how to override equals and hashcode correctly.

This will work better:

```
/**
 * Demo equals override
 * User: mduffy
 * Date: 8/10/2017
 * Time: 10:45 AM
 * @link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45616794/arraylist-contains-method-not-work-as-i-would-except
 */
public class Foo {

    private final String value;

    public Foo(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Foo)) return false;

        Foo foo = (Foo) o;

        return value != null ? value.equals(foo.value) : foo.value == null;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return value != null ? value.hashCode() : 0;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Foo{");
        sb.append("value='").append(value).append('\'');
        sb.append('}');
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help , I did tried it , but now it return `false` for both .
downvote not from me

Comment: @Michael No. for example, the TO's `equals` method isn't reflexive (not sure if that's the term): `a.equals(b)` is not always the same as `b.equals(a);`. This default is one of the reason that it doesn't work

Comment: @Nathan Symmetric. There's a list of terms [on the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)). Reflexive would be `x.equals(x) == true`

Comment: Very absolute a term.  Joshua Bloch lays out exactly how to do it properly.  If you don't follow his recommendation, it's wrong.  Simple.  His implementation can be proven to be reflexive, symmetric, and transitive.  All essential for getting it right.

Comment: @Michael Thanks. On the side, the equals method **must** also be reflexive :p At least it's expected to be. An implementation of `equals` that break any of those criterias is by definition **wrong**, so I think @duffymo 's wording was OK.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is in your equals override: you are comparing o.toString() vs this.value.

to get it working this are your options:

1. Override the `toString` method on your Foo class to return `value`
2. Change the last part to `this.value.equals(o.getValue())` // have to create the getter