# comparing an object to an arrayList of objects

Tags: java, equals

I created two classes, a driver and a GUI frame class. In the Driver Class is where i put my arrayList of user objects. But when calling a method from the GUI frame class, the value being returned is 0.

I've tried using a for each loop to compare each object implicitly.

This is the method i'm using to compare the object of temporary users to existing users.

```
public boolean confirm(boolean loggedIn, int tempStudentNo, int tempPin) {

    //Creation of temporary object for comparison with existing one
    DriverMain temp = new DriverMain(tempStudentNo, tempPin);

    if (getCreation().contains(temp)) {
        System.out.println("user pass");
        setLoggedIn(true);
    } 

    else {
        System.out.println("user fail");
    }
    return loggedIn;

}
```

I expect the user to pass. But the result is always "user fail".
    Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Does `DriverMain` override `equals` method?

Comment: Does your `DriverMain` class, override the `equals` method?

Comment: i don't think so, i didn't override any method in this project

Comment: @JonathanCarlos `contains` uses `equals()`, so you need to implement value equality in your `DriverMain`. If you put them in a `HashSet` (and even if not), you need to override `hashcode()` as well.

Comment: could you give me an example please, i think i'd understand it better then

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8180430/how-to-override-equals-method-in-java) on how to get your `equals()` working.

Comment: so i basically converted each string variable into an integer, and compared them individually. and it worked, thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

This answer is based on your response to the comment(s) asking: "Does your `DriverMain` class, override the `equals` method?"...

In order to use either an (Array)List, HashTable, HashSet or HashMap, etc. you need to override a "couple" of methods in your `DriverMain` class.
For a List, Set, etc.. and some other Collection Types or Map/HashTable to evaluate if your object is a member of its content, you need to provide it with a way to compare the object you are passing to it and the objects it currently holds.

**List**
The `contains(Object o)` method uses the Object's `equals(Object o)` method to compare your Object `o` to any Object `x` (a member of the List Collection).

For more information on this please visit the following link(s): https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/objectclass.html https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html

**Set**
The `contains(Object o)` method uses the Object's `hashCode()` and `equals(Object o)` method to compare your Object `o` to any Object `x` (a member of the Set Collection).

For more information on this please visit the following link(s): https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/objectclass.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/set.html

**Map**
The `containsKey(Object o)` method uses the Object's `hashCode()` and `equals(Object o)` method to compare your Object `o` to any Object `x` (a member of the Map Interface).

For more information on this please visit the following link(s): https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/objectclass.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html

**Important note**
*There are more ways to approach such a situation, all depending on its implementation. For example: `TreeSet` and `TreeMap` do not make use of the `hashCode()` method.*

Comment: Not totally correct. For instance `TreeSet/Map` don't use hashcode at all, they also use `compare()` instead of `equals()`. `HashSet/Map` uses hashcode **and** equals.

Comment: I'll make this more clear, tried to make this clear in my bottom comment. I agree, it all depends on your implementation, but by "default" this is the most common way of approach. It's clear that the user asking this does not have a lot of experience with Java and will not make use of `TreeSet/Map` in the future; or any other implementation other then `ArrayList`, `HashSet` or `HashMap`