# MockMvc test POST request returns error : Actual invocations have different arguments:

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, mockmvc

I am new to backend testing and I am testing my spring boot app with MockMvc. However, when I want to test my Post request, I have the error mentioned in the title when I use

```
verify(userService,atLeastOnce()).addUser(user1);
```

The error log is as follows:

```
{"id":1,"name":"Burakhan Aksoy","email":"burak@burak.com","gender":"Male","phoneNumber":"12321"}

MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = POST
      Request URI = /users
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = [Content-Type:"application/json;charset=UTF-8", Content-Length:"96"]
             Body = {"id":1,"name":"Burakhan Aksoy","email":"burak@burak.com","gender":"Male","phoneNumber":"12321"}
    Session Attrs = {}

Handler:
             Type = io.thebman.restapitesting.controllers.UserController
           Method = io.thebman.restapitesting.controllers.UserController#addUser(User)

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = null

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 201
    Error message = null
          Headers = [Content-Type:"application/json"]
     Content type = application/json
             Body = {"id":1,"name":"Burakhan Aksoy","email":"burak@burak.com","gender":"Male","phoneNumber":"12321"}
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []


Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
io.thebman.restapitesting.service.UserService#0 bean.addUser(
    io.thebman.restapitesting.view.User@1b5a1d85
);
-> at io.thebman.restapitesting.UserControllerTest.postUserThenValidateUserAddedSuccessfully(UserControllerTest.java:119)
Actual invocations have different arguments:
io.thebman.restapitesting.service.UserService#0 bean.addUser(
    io.thebman.restapitesting.view.User@31e130bf
);
-> at io.thebman.restapitesting.controllers.UserController.addUser(UserController.java:32)

Comparison Failure: 
<Click to see difference>

Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
io.thebman.restapitesting.service.UserService#0 bean.addUser(
    io.thebman.restapitesting.view.User@1b5a1d85
);
-> at io.thebman.restapitesting.UserControllerTest.postUserThenValidateUserAddedSuccessfully(UserControllerTest.java:119)
Actual invocations have different arguments:
io.thebman.restapitesting.service.UserService#0 bean.addUser(
    io.thebman.restapitesting.view.User@31e130bf
);
-> at io.thebman.restapitesting.controllers.UserController.addUser(UserController.java:32)

    at io.thebman.restapitesting.UserControllerTest.postUserThenValidateUserAddedSuccessfully(UserControllerTest.java:119)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:688)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:206)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:65)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1259)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1259)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:75)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:220)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:53)
```

My UserController class is as follows:

```
package io.thebman.restapitesting.controllers;

import io.thebman.restapitesting.service.UserService;
import io.thebman.restapitesting.view.User;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping("/users/{id}")
    public User getUserById(@PathVariable int id){

        return userService.getUser(id);
    }

    @RequestMapping("/users")
    public List<User> getUsers(){
        return userService.getUsers();
    }

    @PostMapping("/users")
    public @ResponseBody
    ResponseEntity<User> addUser(@RequestBody User user){
        return new ResponseEntity<User>(userService.addUser(user), HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
}
```

My UserControllerTest class as follows:

```
package io.thebman.restapitesting;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import io.thebman.restapitesting.controllers.UserController;
import io.thebman.restapitesting.service.UserService;
import io.thebman.restapitesting.view.User;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.ResultMatcher;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.ContentResultMatchers;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultHandlers;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.*;
import static org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat;

import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.*;

@WebMvcTest(UserController.class)
public class UserControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    private UserController userController;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private UserService userService;

    //Test /users (POST)
    @Test
    public void postUserThenValidateUserAddedSuccessfully() throws Exception {
        User user1 =new User(1,"Burakhan Aksoy",
                "burak@burak.com","Male",
                "12321");

        when(userService.addUser(any(User.class))).thenReturn(user1);

        //Start mocking http request
         mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/users")
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(asJsonString(new User(1,"Burakhan Aksoy",
                        "burak@burak.com","Male",
                        "12321"))))
                .andExpect(status().isCreated())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.id").exists())
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.name").value("Burakhan Aksoy"))
                 .andExpect(jsonPath("$.email").value("burak@burak.com"))
                 .andExpect(jsonPath("$.gender").value("Male"))
                 .andExpect(jsonPath("$.phoneNumber").value("12321"));

        verify(userService,atLeastOnce()).addUser(user1);
//        verifyNoMoreInteractions(userService);
    }
    public static String asJsonString(final Object obj) {
        try {
            final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            final String jsonContent = mapper.writeValueAsString(obj);
            System.out.println(jsonContent);
            return jsonContent;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated

Best,

Comment: Does your `User` class have a properly implemented `equals` method? In your `verify` call, you're expecting it to receiving the argument `user1`, but your controller's handler method is actually calling `addUser` with a new `User` object deseralized from the JSON content. Unless there's a proper `equals` method to compare them, they'll never be equal (iirc).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't have equals method. How can I implement it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8180430/how-to-override-equals-method-in-java

Comment: As a follow up question, even though I override the equals method and make sure they are indeed the same, how can I use it in the test case? I mean I will still be using verify(userService,atLeastOnce()).addUser(user); . so how does overriding equals method and making sure user1 and user are equal help this test case pass?

Comment: The `equals` method is used for you behind the scenes. Mockito will compare what you `verify()` with what is actually passed to `addUser` in your `@PostMapping` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to overload default `hashCode()` and `equals()` method in your User class.

In your scenario, it's considering two different object and comparing based on default Object's method which checks for address.

Edit:
As part of this single test case, you just need to override `equals()` method. But failing to override `hashCode()`, you might face issues in future when you use any `Hash` related collections like `HashTable, HashMap etc.`

Refer this for more details: [Why do I need to override the equals and hashCode methods in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265503/why-do-i-need-to-override-the-equals-and-hashcode-methods-in-java)