# Java Deep Comparison Returns False when Comparing a Deep Copy

Tags: java, compare, overriding, copy-constructor, deep-copy

I created an abstract class Fruit, which overrides the equals() method.  Then I created a subclass, Orange, which overrides the copy() and the equals() method.  In my test file, TestFruit.java, I am creating an array of oranges and testing their methods.  I am trying to create a deep copy of orange and do a deep comparison between the parent orange and the copy.  However, in my output, the comparison always returns false.  I checked the parent and the copy's attributes and they do seem to be the same.  Any pointers would be appreciated.  I am pretty new to Java and copying.  I attached my code below.

Fruit.java:

```
package juicer;

import copy.Copyable;

public abstract class Fruit implements Copyable, Cloneable
{
    private double mass;
    private boolean isJuicedRemoved;

    protected Fruit(double theMass)
            throws IllegalMassException
    {
        {
            if (theMass <= 0)
            {
                throw new IllegalMassException(theMass);
            }
            else
            {
                this.mass = theMass;
                this.isJuicedRemoved = false;
            }
        }
    }

    protected Fruit(Fruit fruit)
    {
        this.mass = fruit.mass;
        this.isJuicedRemoved = fruit.isJuicedRemoved;
    }

    public double getMass()
    {
        return mass;
    }

    public boolean getIsJuicedExtracted()
    {
        return isJuicedRemoved;
    }

    protected void setMass(double value)
    {
        this.mass = value;
    }

    protected abstract double juiceRatio();

    public double extractJuice()
    {
        double liquidMass = amountJuice();

        if (!isJuicedRemoved)
        {
            isJuicedRemoved = true;
            mass -= liquidMass;
        }

        return liquidMass;
    }

    public double amountJuice()
    {
        if (isJuicedRemoved) return 0.0;

        return mass * juiceRatio();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj)
    {
        // Steps to override the equals() method():

        // Step 1: Test if obj is an instance of Fruit.
        //         If it is not, then return false.
        if (!(obj instanceof Fruit)) return false;

        // Step 2: Cast obj to an Fruit.
        Fruit rhs = (Fruit)obj;

        // Step 3: Test if the data fields of the invoking object are
        //         equal to the ones in rhs using a deep comparison
        //         and return this result.
        return super.equals(obj) && // test for equality in the super class
                mass == rhs.mass &&
                isJuicedRemoved == rhs.isJuicedRemoved;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode()
    {
        int result = super.hashCode();
        result = 31*result + Double.hashCode(mass);
        result = 31*result + Boolean.hashCode(isJuicedRemoved);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException
    {
        Fruit objectClone = (Fruit)super.clone();

        objectClone.mass = mass;
        objectClone.isJuicedRemoved = isJuicedRemoved;

        return objectClone;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "\tmass = " + mass +
                "\n\tisJuiceExtracted = " + isJuicedRemoved + "\n";
    }
}
```

Orange.java:

```
package juicer;

public class Orange extends Fruit
{
    public Orange(double mass)
    {
        super(mass);
    }

    // copy constructor
    public Orange(Orange other)
    {
        super(other);
    }

    @Override
    protected double juiceRatio()
    {
        return 0.87;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj)
    {
        // Steps to override the equals() method():

        // Step 1: Test if obj is an instance of Orange.
        //         If it is not, then return false.
        if (!(obj instanceof Orange)) return false;

        // Step 2: Cast obj to an Orange.
        // This step is not needed since the only data fields this
        // class has are the ones it inherits.

        // Step 3: Test if the data fields of the invoking object are
        //         equal to the ones in rhs using a deep comparison
        //         and return this result.
        return super.equals(obj);
    }

    @Override
    public Object copy()
    {
        return new Orange(this);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Orange:\n" + super.toString();
    }
}
```

TestFruit.java:

```
package test;

import juicer.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class TestFruit
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Orange[] oranges = new Orange[1];

        //Random double generator for mass
        Random rd = new Random();

        //create oranges
        for (int i = 0; i <= oranges.length - 1; i++ )
        {
            oranges[i] = new Orange(rd.nextDouble());
        }

        for (Orange orange : oranges)
        {
            Orange orangeCopy = new Orange(orange);

            if (orange == orangeCopy)
            {
                System.out.print("The comparison is true!");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.print("Does not match.");
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the common misconceptions in Java is the use of `==` vs `.equals()`. When you use `==` to compare two objects in Java, internally it's comparing its memory address. `==` does **not** actually call `.equals()`.

In this case, you have two distinct orange objects, so the comparison will always return false.

If you use `a.equals(b)`, then it will actually invoke your `equals` method which you implemented.

As @Andreas pointed out in the comments, there's another issue. Calling `super.equals(obj)` in `Fruit` will call the superclass implementation of `equals`, and the superclass of `Fruit` is `Object`. `Object.equals()` behaves the same as `==` (i.e. also checking for reference equality). Overriding `.equals()` is [not trivial](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49608588/3813411), so it can often be nice to have the IDE generate it for you.

In contrast with a language like C++, Java does not have operator overloading. This means that you can't define a different implementation for `==`. This is why it's best practice to always call `.equals()` when comparing any non-primitive types (unless you're explicitly checking reference equality, which is rare).

Comment: Of course, since the `equals()` implementation erroneously calls `Object.equals()`, the result will be the same as using `==`.

Comment: @Andreas, ah, good point—yes, `super.equals(obj)` in the `Fruit` superclass will call `Object.equals()` which will compare based on object identity as well.