# Java equals() method always returning false

Tags: java, equals

i'm trying to compare to objects using the equals method but it always returns false

```
public class main {
    public static boolean match(house h1,house h2) {
        if(h2.equals(h1)) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        house myHouse1 = new house("jj",5,5);
        house myHouse2 = new house("jj",5,5);
        
        System.out.println(match(myHouse1,myHouse2));

    }

}
```

Comment: How is equals implemented in house?

Comment: Does class `house` override method [equals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8180430/how-to-override-equals-method-in-java) ?

Comment: If you did not override `equals` and `hashCode` in `house`, then yes, `h1` and `h2` are two distinct instances.

Comment: Unless you explicitly override the `equals(Object o)` method in your custom type it will just compare the instance hash instead of the contents of the object.

Comment: You should override equals method in house class

Comment: You can automatically override `equals` and `hashCode` method in your `house` class with IntelliJ. Right click on class -> Generate -> equals and hashCode

Answer (score 3):

**You have to implement the `equals` method yourself.**

The `equals` method does not magically test whether two instances of your custom class are considered "equal" to eachother. You must define when two of your objects are equal yourself.

Since you did not implement `equals` yourself, then the implementation of `Object` is selected (in your case), which only compares by *identity*. Two objects created by `new` *always* have distinct identities, that is, two separate chunks in memory, despite having exactly the same fields.

So you need to *override* `equals` (and, by contract, also `hashCode`). Note that the `equals` method must accept an `Object` rather than a `House`<sup>1</sup>, that is, `public boolean equals(Object other) { ... }`.

#### What are the options to implement `equals`?

You have a few options to implement `equals` (and `hashCode`):

- Write it yourself by hand. More information: [How to override equals method in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8180430/how-to-override-equals-method-in-java)
- Use your IDE to generate them for you. Fenio already provided how to do this in IntelliJ [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70018832/java-equals-method-always-returning-false/70019117#comment123774187_70018832). In Netbeans, open the class, right-click on the source code and click on <kbd>Insert Code...</kbd> → <kbd>equals() and hashCode()...</kbd> and then select the fields to include in the comparison.
- Use [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) to generate them for you, using the [`@EqualsAndHashCode`](https://projectlombok.org/features/EqualsAndHashCode) annotation.
- Turn your `House` into a `record`<sup>2</sup> and you get `equals` and `hashCode` for free.

---

<sup>1</sup> Class names should be written in PascalCase according to the Java Naming Conventions, so `house` should be `House`.
<sup>2</sup> Records are available since Java 16 (and in Java 14 and 15 as *preview feature*s).