# Need to write a equals-method to check if a book is the same as another book but one book contains multiple values

Tags: java, equals

Below is my code at this moment, I need to add to the equals method so when I create a two books they will only be equal if both of the attributes are the same. Hopefully you guys can help.

```java
public class Book {
    private String title;
    private boolean bound;

    Book(String title, boolean bound) {
        this.title = title;
        this.bound = bound;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if ((obj instanceof Book)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: you could use equatable instead, read about it.

Comment: btw, if you override equals, you also need to override hashCode. If you know about that, carry on! :-) If not, definitely do a search about the topic.

Comment: Addressed by: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49608588/11374957

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct implementation would be:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if(this == obj)
        return true;
    if(!(obj instanceof Book))
        return false;
    Book other = (Book) obj;
    return bound == other.bound && Objects.equals(title, other.title);
}
```

Both object properties are respected!

** **Update** **

To avoid using `instanceof` you should use

```
if(this.getClass() != obj.getClass())
   return false;
```

Thanks user16320675 for the hint!

Comment: controversial use of `instanceof` instead of checking for same class - according javadoc of `equals`, it should be symmetric, that is, `x.equals(y)` should return same result as `y.equals(x)`

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. However, the `instanceof` will always be `true` here if you are actually comparing to books. The below should work.

```
class Book {

     private String title;
     private boolean bound;

     public Book(String title, boolean bound) {
         this.title = title;
         this.bound = bound;
     }

     public String getTitle(){
          return this.title;
     }
     public boolean isBound(){
          return this.bound;
     }
     @Override
     public boolean equals(Obj obj) {
          if(!(obj instanceof Book)){
               return false;
          }
          if (((Book) obj).isBound() == this.isBound() && ((Book) obj).getTitle().equals(this.getTitle())) {
               return true;
          }
          return false;
     }
}
```

Now you can compare two books.

```
Book b1  = new Book(new String("Title1"), true);
Book b2  = new Book(new String("Title2"), true);
Book b3  = new Book(new String("Title1"), true);

System.out.println(b1.equals(b2)); // Output is false
System.out.println(b1.equals(b3)); // Output is true
```

Comment: Your equals does not override the equals method of Object

Comment: @Benjamin W. - You're almost there.  You need "equals(Object o)", not "Book book".  See [Thilo Schwarz's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72997340/421195) implementation below.  And "==" is wrong for Java string comparison.  Please [Edit] your reply, before somebody marks you down ;)

Comment: Thanks I edited it to include type check .